# How to get the name of the lookup field instead of id in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, js

```
    import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
    import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
    
    const FIELDS = ['Payment__c.Company__c']; 

    export default class PrintCheck extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement){
    @api recordId;  

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
        payment;
    
        handleClick(event) {
            var company = this.payment.data.fields.Company__c.value;
            console.log('Need name Here Instead of ID'+ company);
        }
    }
```

It returns id in console.log, but i need name of the lookup field....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Name in your fields definition

```
     const FIELDS = ['Payment__c.Company__r.Name']; 
     
      handleClick(event) {
            const company = this.payment.data.fields.Company__r.value.fields.Name.value;            
            console.log('Need name Here Instead of ID'+ company);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks It worked Klecool :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: You can also use import statements and getFieldDisplayValue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a use case for getFieldDisplayValue:

```
import { getFieldDisplayValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import COMPANYNAMEFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Payment__c.Company__c';
```

...

```
const FIELDS = [COMPANYNAMEFIELD];
```

...

```
var company = getFieldDisplayValue(this.payment.data, COMPANYNAMEFIELD);
```